# Node.Js- Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection

Tags: mysql, node.js, server, xampp, connection

Two weeks ago I deployed my first application as part of my new job (Woo Hoo! :)), but every night since I deployed it- the app crashes.
The server-side was built with Node.js, and I'm using XAMPP and MYSQL to run the DataBase.
So this is the error I continuously get:
[image]

I was searching for a solution, and found this code:

```
var connection;
function handleDisconnect() {
    connection = mysql.createConnection(con); // Recreate the connection, since
                                                    // the old one cannot be reused.
  
    connection.connect(function(err) {              // The server is either down
      if(err) {                                     // or restarting (takes a while sometimes).
        // console.log('error when connecting to db:', err);
        setTimeout(handleDisconnect, 2000); // We introduce a delay before attempting to reconnect,
      }                                     // to avoid a hot loop, and to allow our node script to
    });                                     // process asynchronous requests in the meantime.
                                            // If you're also serving http, display a 503 error.
    connection.on('error', function(err) {
    //   console.log('db error', err);
      if(err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') { // Connection to the MySQL server is usually
        handleDisconnect();                         // lost due to either server restart, or a
      } else {                                      // connnection idle timeout (the wait_timeout
        throw err;                                  // server variable configures this)
      }
    });
  }
  
  handleDisconnect();
```

I pasted this code after the createConnection function:

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "EXAMPLE FOR STUCK OVER FLOW",
    user: "EXAMPLE FOR STUCK OVER FLOW",
    password: "EXAMPLE FOR STUCK OVER FLOW",
    database: "EXAMPLE FOR STUCK OVER FLOW"
});
```

I will really appreciate for your advice!

Thanks!!!

Comment: Is the new code working now? The one which tries to make a new connection in case of a MySQL PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST  error? In my opinion, we can use the MySQL pool here. It will kick out a dead connection and create a new one when requested for. So you don't need to write handleDisconnect code like above. Let module do the hard work for you. Refer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#server-disconnects

Comment: Hi @surajs21 ! Thank you for your help!
The code is working, but it keeps crashing at night.
I was reading what you've sent, but I'm not completely sure I understand it.

Comment: Let me try to reproduce it at my end. I have a suspicion that when we are going to create a clean new connection in case of an error, then we should also close the previous connection using `connection.destroy();`. But let me try it first.